# Porting newlib into cross-compiler

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, binutils, newlib

I am using [this tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) to create a cross-compiler.

I followed the gcc cross-compiler tutorial and went to the [porting newlib](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib). Everything worked fine till I tried compiling it by issuing

`make all install`

when I got the following error:

```
WARNING: `makeinfo' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if
         you modified a `.texi' or `.texinfo' file, or any other file
         indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.  The spurious
         call might also be the consequence of using a buggy `make' (AIX,
         DU, IRIX).  You might want to install the `Texinfo' package or
         the `GNU make' package.  Grab either from any GNU archive site.
```

and the compilation stops.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

I have tried:

- using different gcc, binutils and newlib versions (about 5 different combinations)
- installing Texinfo
- correcting makeinfo path

My cross-compiler works perfectly without the newlib just that it of course cannot include the libraries.

Comment: Check why this warning keeps pop up by read the configure file.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have makeinfo installed, it may not recognize newer versions.  The following patch works.  Copy below and save as "configure.patch", save it where the configure script is, then type "patch -p1 < configure.patch".

```
--- newlib-1.14.0-bak/configure 2008-06-10 20:49:16.918036351 +0200
+++ newlib-1.14.0/configure 2008-06-10 21:21:35.750035824 +0200
@@ -3542,7 +3542,7 @@
     # For an installed makeinfo, we require it to be from texinfo 4.2 or
     # higher, else we use the "missing" dummy.
     if ${MAKEINFO} --version \
-       | egrep 'texinfo[^0-9]*([1-3][0-9]|4\.[2-9]|[5-9])' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
+       | egrep 'texinfo[^0-9]*([1-3][0-9]|4\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])|[5-9])' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
       :
     else
       MAKEINFO="$MISSING makeinfo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install 6809 GDB and got this error. I fixed by going into Makefile and changing

```
MAKEINFO = /opt/binutils-gdb/missing makeinfo
```

to

```
MAKEINFO = makeinfo
```

I also had to do this with

```
BISON = bison
YACC = bison -y
FLEX = flex
LEX = flex
```

However make got stuck with some bison function definitions:

```
macroexp.o: In function `get_character_constant':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/macroexp.c:364: undefined reference to `c_parse_escape'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `c_parse'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `c_error'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x148): undefined reference to `c_parse'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x150): undefined reference to `c_error'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x268): undefined reference to `c_parse'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x270): undefined reference to `c_error'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x388): undefined reference to `c_parse'
c-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x390): undefined reference to `c_error'
d-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `c_parse'
d-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `c_error'
f-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `f_parse'
f-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `f_error'
objc-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `c_parse'
objc-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `c_error'
go-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `go_parse'
go-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `go_error'
m2-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `m2_parse'
m2-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `m2_error'
opencl-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `c_parse'
opencl-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `c_error'
p-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `pascal_parse'
p-lang.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x30): undefined reference to `pascal_error'
cp-support.o: In function `mangled_name_to_comp':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:644: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_to_comp'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:629: undefined reference to `cp_new_demangle_parse_info'
cp-support.o: In function `cp_canonicalize_string_full':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:534: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_to_comp'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:541: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:545: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_parse_free'
cp-support.o: In function `inspect_type':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:260: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_to_comp'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:264: undefined reference to `cp_merge_demangle_parse_infos'
cp-support.o: In function `replace_typedefs':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:441: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
cp-support.o: In function `replace_typedefs_qualified_name':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:368: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:343: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
cp-support.o: In function `cp_canonicalize_string':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:582: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_to_comp'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:587: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:588: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_parse_free'
cp-support.o: In function `cp_class_name_from_physname':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:743: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_parse_free'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:738: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
cp-support.o: In function `method_name_from_physname':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:826: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:830: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_parse_free'
cp-support.o: In function `cp_func_name':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:847: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_to_comp'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:855: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:857: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_parse_free'
cp-support.o: In function `cp_remove_params':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:876: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_to_comp'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:903: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_parse_free'
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:901: undefined reference to `cp_comp_to_string'
cp-support.o: In function `do_demangled_name_parse_free_cleanup':
/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb/cp-support.c:108: undefined reference to `cp_demangled_name_parse_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1174: recipe for target 'gdb' failed
make[2]: *** [gdb] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb/gdb'
Makefile:8590: recipe for target 'all-gdb' failed
make[1]: *** [all-gdb] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/vectrex/binutils-gdb'
Makefile:827: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After removing the entire directory and redownloading, the makefile was all correct (no missing directory) and make and make install completed fully. So perhaps the modifications to the makefile weren't needed and I just needed to have bison, flex, and makeinfo installed.